# how to preserve 'input' in <form> when the page refreshes, or stop the page refreshing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, input

i have a  element of type 'input'. Is there any way to stop the page submitting and refreshing when i push enter in the 'input' field? and If not, can i make it so that the input content is still there?

I already have this in my jquery code :

```
    event.preventDefault();
```

but it does not prevent a reset of the input field contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(YOUR_FORM_SELECTOR).find('input').keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which === 13 )
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will ignore all presses of enter for all input elements in your form.  If you want it to take effect just for one input element, set the keypress handler just on that one.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thanks for the succinct answer.